# Таймаут для сторонней функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, windows, timeout

Есть некая функция сторонней библиотеки `foo`, которую я не могу менять. Как в моём коде произвести вызов с такой логикой: 1) вызвать `foo`; 2) продолжить выполнение следующих команд либо по окончании `foo`, либо по прошествии `N` секунд? Надо чтобы работало как на линуксе, так и на винде.

Comment: Например https://github.com/bitranox/wrapt_timeout_decorator там про Windows специальное примечание отдельно есть

Comment: @CrazyElf это же декоратор, а я не могу модифицировать код функции. Только если делать врапперы для всех функций библиотеки с этим декоратором

Comment: Можно декорировать функцию без синтаксического сахара c @

Comment: @Alpensin переприсвоить значение `foo`? Так же всё равно надо враппер писать

Comment: @Ruslan В доке есть пример использования https://github.com/bitranox/wrapt_timeout_decorator#use-as-function-not-as-decorator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут нужны уточнения

1. Мы ждем от foo каких-то значений?
2. Должна ли foo прекращать работу при таймауте или пусть работает дальше, хоть мы и не ждём уже результата.

Самый простой вариант, если на оба вопроса выше ответ нет

**Модуль conc.py**

```
from some import foo
from threading import Thread


def main():
    print("main started")
    thread = Thread(target=foo)
    thread.start()
    thread.join(timeout=2)
    print("main finished")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Модуль some.py**

```
from time import sleep


def foo():
    sleep(5)
    with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("k")
```